# Dungeon generation algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to create an algorithm which would generate dungeon with following rules:

- In the center is 2x2 cells starting area. Only one side is accessible to a corridor (see blue square)
- Map contains two 3x3 areas. When laying out map, they act as corridors. (see green squares)
- Every room is 3x2 cells rectangle.
- Each room must have exactly one entry point (door) from a corridor.

  - If no corridors available, room's entry point can be a secret passage from neighboring room. (see red squares)
- No room can have more than one secret passage.
- No corridor can have width of more than one cell at any point.
- No cell in the map can remain unused.
- Map is a rectangle with predetermined dimensions

The last two conditions is what's giving me problems. I can't come up with an idea on how to handle it other then iterative and/or random approach, both of which are excruciatingly slow at best. What would be a good way to handle this *dungeon efficiency* problem in reasonable time?

Here is an example of such dungeon with map size 24x21:

[image: Dungeon layout]

Comment: Do you have any (pseudo)code to share so far?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm, maybe using a modified prim's or kruskal's algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

1. For *•No cell in the map can remain unused* perhaps perform a post-process that converts all such into hidden rooms, with a randomly created hidden exit/entry.
2. For *•Map is a rectangle with predetermined dimensions* perhaps establish a minimum room width and upon approaching within twice the allocated limit set the width of the next room to the remaining space.

The key to many efficiency challenges in game programming is to choose suitable approximations that will be invisible (or nearly so) to the player.

Comment: the problem is that all rooms must be *exactly* 3x2 or 2x3 cells of the map. See layout. All rooms are 3x2.